# Are there real world examples demonstrating reasonable performance improvement by using move semantics?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, c++11

(I've asked a similar question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879687/any-real-world-cases-demonstrating-reasonable-performance-improvement-by-using-m?noredirect=1) but unfortunately it might not be proper, so I also put here; please kindly point out if you think it's a duplicate.)

I've heard [many](http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/the-biggest-changes-in-c11-and-why-you-should-care/) [words](http://cpprocks.com/9-reasons-to-start-using-c11/) about the *move semantics* (essentially rvalue) introduced in C++11. *In theory*, it should bring much performance improvement due to the fact it avoids unnecessary *copies*.

However, there have already been [some optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)s for legacy code during compilation to deal with the inefficient temporary copies, such as:

- (named) [return value optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)
- constructor copy elision

And additionally for frequently used data structures, some C++ standard libraries use special optimizations (e.g., small string optimization for `std::string`).

More importantly, although some pieces of legacy code are *really* inefficient they don't result in much latency since they are

- not frequently invoked
- modern computers have enough physical memories for them

So I'm asking: are there *real-world examples* that greatly accelerate the performance when using modern C++ (C++11/14/17) syntax, or improve the performance by a reasonable percentage (e.g., >10%) *overall*?

I expect that the answer can be any of the 3 categories:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::size_t;

size_t const MAX = NNN;  // NNN is specified by -DNNN=xxx option
size_t const NUM = NNN/100;

vector<int> factory(size_t size) {
  vector<int> v;
  for (size_t i = 0u; i < size; ++i) {
    v.push_back(i);
  }
  return v;
}

// Version 1
/// void doubles(vector<int> & v) {
// Version 2
void doubles(vector<int> && v) {
  for (size_t i = 0u; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    v[i] = v[i] * 2;
  }
}

int main() {
// Version 1
/// vector<int> v = factory(MAX);
/// doubles(v);
// Version 2
  doubles(factory(MAX));
}
```

1. Some performance bugs/bottlenecks existing in real world repositories that can be handled modern C++ well.
2. Some *profiling* for *a piece of code* that show the improvement.
3. Starting by modifying some of the *above* trivial code to help me get an example that can bring the performance benefit.

And the improvement can still be viewed with `default` (e.g., `-O0`) compilation options (so `-fno-elide-constructors` is not allowed during compilation) by gcc *`or`* clang *`or`* MSVC.

I ask this question because I was doing a survey on the move semantics impact on performance for real world programs but after I tried some (trivial) code and did some basic profiling myself, I found that I simply cannot find the significant differences. So please forgive me if you feel it stupid/pedantic.

Comment: This boils down to a poll which is off-topic for the site.

Comment: @GlenH7 Thanks and I saw your comments in SO. Can you tell where can I ask?

Comment: I don't know of any StackExchange site where this question would work.  I would recommend chat, but I don't know which of the C++ rooms to recommend.

Comment: @GlenH7 THanks. Yes, I'll try to find the proper chat room tomorrow.

Comment: As you have noted by yourself, move semantics does not introduce a kind of performance optimization which was not possible without it beforehand. Move semantics just increases the ease-of-use for that type of optimization. So IMHO you are asking the wrong question. Maybe it could make sense to ask for examples showing how the ease-of-use increases, not the performance.

Comment: @DocBrown I was thinking that there might be some cases in which a few APIs (e.g., library public interface) cannot be changed and only move semantics can (safely) avoid unnecessary copies. Are there?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/list-questions/info

Comment: @gnat you mean *good examples* in the title? just removed that:-)

Comment: @HongxuChen What gnat means is that the overall StackExchange family of Q&A sites are designed for questions that have canonical answers. That basically means the answers should eventually converge to some consensus, at which point no more new answers would be needed. Questions that have (1) contextual answers, (2) assemblage of things (resources, examples, etc.) are not welcomed, because those questions would eventually have too many answers, and too few that could be upvoted (i.e. too few that would have the merits to stand out).

Comment: @rwong Got it. Now I know why I asked a bad question. What do you suggest if you asked this question?

Comment: This is an awkward question since probably the real-world performance-critical apps that would notice a performance difference would have already avoided wasteful deep copying in their critical paths. Maybe people working outside of performance-critical fields who just do things like represent matrices with `vector<vector<float>>` would notice. Performance-critical areas that are always paying attention to timings and measurements would tend to avoid this kind of stuff outright in the hot paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an overview of the benefits and best-practices on move semantics, please watch some of the [conference recordings on the **isocpp** website](https://isocpp.org/blog/category/video-on-demand). 
*(At the bottom there's a link to older recordings.)*

---

Bjarne Stroustrup provide a prime motivating example on his website.

http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#rval

Just consider the typical implementation of `std::swap`, assuming that this method *does not have special access to the type*. 

<sub>The sample code and comments below are copied verbatim from the link above.</sub>

```
template<class T> swap(T& a, T& b)      // "old style swap"
{
    T tmp(a);   // now we have two copies of a
    a = b;      // now we have two copies of b
    b = tmp;    // now we have two copies of tmp (aka a)
}
```

When new objects are created, it incurs the cost of copying that object. Most of the time, this implies *deep copying - share nothing*, because each object must be prepared to be independently modifiable, because there's nothing to imply otherwise.

But in this example, it is clear that `tmp` is a temporary. What can we do to avoid the cost of deep copying in this case?

---

As @DocBrown points out in comment, the benefits of move semantics is dependent on:

- The coding style
- The implementation of data structures used most heavily in the code

---

In object oriented programming, there is a contentious issue: **copying or sharing**? (Another contentious issue is the *mutable or immutable*.)

Most software programs will spend time copying stuff. The questions are:

- Does the situation require copying?
- Is there a cheaper way of copying?

If two or more instances of code need access to the same object, and if all of these instances promise they will never modify the object (i.e. cause its states to change), then perhaps sharing the object reference (by pointer or other means) may be sufficient.

If one instance of code needs to make a copy so that the object can be modified, it will not benefit from most "make copy cheap" scheme.

Sometimes it is a middle ground. An object has multiple properties, and the code wants to make a copy so that one or several properties can be modified. In this case, "make copy cheap" would require one to allow sharing of unchanged properties between the old and new object. *(Note: move semantics **does not** enable this. I mention this because move semantics have to face a number of competing **other kinds of semantics**.)*

---

C++ code that is written to a C style, with its heavy use of pointers, may not see any benefit, because such code already freely share any data structure by  sharing pointers, and do so without much syntactic safeguards.

C++ code that already implements reference counting (such as [OpenCV's `Mat` class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)), [Microsoft COM pointers (`com_ptr_t`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx), etc., allow multiple instances of code to share the same piece of data.

---

The kind of C++ code that may benefit from move semantics are those that

1. Mainly rely on STL data structures (most importantly `std::vector`),
2. Uses "value semantics" heavily (makes objects immutable, makes copies of objects heavily, prefers copying values to sharing references), and
3. In order for its performance improvements to be measurable,

   - It should be doing some heavy-lifting (i.e. the amount of data and computation should be reasonably big to be measurable)
   - It should not be dominated by other types of bottlenecks (such as disk, IO, database, etc.).

---

One may say that each of those factors are questionable, and rightly so.

There are C++ programs that implement **their own** reference counting, reference-sharing schemes, lazy (on-demand) evaluation, asynchronous operations or promise-futures, etc., long before C++11 was conceived. These C++ programming environments chose a trajectory that make them largely independent of the evolutions of C++. From a historical perspective, they might be right, because the evolutions of C++ had apparently been stagnant for a decade or so, where most of the innovations are thought to be doable with library code (such as the Boost Libraries) without requiring changes to the language standard.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification and the great suggestions for finding the code examples. I'll follow your words can make such examples if I cannot find the real one.

Comment: There are a number of places where code which knows that it holds the *only* pointer to an object can benefit from such knowledge.  If code exposes an independent copy of a pointer, it may be difficult for it to discover when all independent copies have ceased to exist.  On the other hand, it's often *much* easier, but almost as useful, for code to know that no independent copies of the pointer have *ever* existed.  Move semantics increase the number of cases where code which will often hold the only reference to an object will be able to know that and exploit it.